# PHP function not accepting parameter

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm currently experiencing a problem with a php function. I have declared a function:

```
    function edit_content($array, $id = NULL){
        //code
    }
```

Where `$array` is an array passed to the function and `$id` is an optional integer value.
When I call the function for example like this:

```
edit_content($content_array, 2);
```

the value `2` doesn't get passed.

Why wouldn't the value not get passed? Does it have something to do with the array being passed?

Comment: How did you find out that the `2` didn't get passed?

Comment: Try to add to your description, what value you provide with $content_array. Maybe there you got the problem.

Comment: It works just fine for me... http://codepad.viper-7.com/gTEogO

Comment: Show us the internals of `edit_content` and where you fail to use `$id`.

Comment: Are you maybe overwriting the int passed to the function? Or misspelling a variable in the body of your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the code after all but in cache. I forgot to clean the cache after changing the ajax call a bit and it resulted in calling the function under different condition (where ID is not passed because it is not needed.

Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for taking your time.
Have a great day!